# Autonomous vehicle sharing and reservation problem

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to make a objective function and constraints for this paper about autonomous vehicle sharing and reservation. I want to make toy case out of it right now, but i am currently stucked. I put constraints according to the paper, but it says it's having **syntax error, unexpected( identifier)**. Attached is the code I wrote. Please give me a hand.
[the code i wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKUHn.png)[the one i am trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsv6b.png)

Comment: Rather than providing a link to an image of your code, please cut and paste the code here so it's easier to see and work with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n=3;
range N=1..n;


tuple arc
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

{arc} A={<1,2>};
int m[A]=[7];

dvar int+ x [<i,j> in A];

subject to
{
  forall(i in N) forall(<i,j> in A) x[<i,j>]<=m[<i,j>];
}
```

works fine